# Pandas DataFrame column naming conventions

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any commonly used Pandas DataFrame column naming convention? Is [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommended here (ex. instance variables)?

Concious that lots of data is loaded from external sources with headers but I'm curious what is the correct approach when I have to name/rename the columns on my own?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some people tend to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (lower case with underscores) so that they can access the column using period like this `df.my_column`

I tend to always access columns using the `df['my_column']` syntax because it avoids confusion with DataFrame methods and properties, and it easier to extend to slices and fancy indexing, so the snake case is not necessary.

In short, I think you should use whatever is clearest to a potential reader.

Answer (score 9):

One more thing to keep in mind, if your application also makes use of relational databases - I would recommend that you keep your Pandas naming conventions consistent with the column names of your relational database tables.

Comment: e.g. in the case of PostgreSQL and most(?) others, that means all lowercase letters (case sensitivity for columns in databases requires a lot of extra quotes in queries). I ran into this headache when I started using a database after I wrote a ton a pandas code. Seems the cleanest way forward is to go back and change all my pandas code to use lowercase column names.

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear guidance from `pandas` founding fathers and the choice is really between already mentioned *snake* vs *Pascal (camel) case*, or `df[my_column]`  vs  `df[MyColumn]`, and is a matter of preference. A lot of `R` packages use *snake* *case* for dataframes.  I'd say *snake case* is more readable while *Pascal case* require fewer characters.