# PEP8 guidance for column names in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pep8

Is there a standard naming convention that is suggestible for columns in Pandas Dataframes ?

As I looked around, this seems to be the most relevant question or answer on this topic: [Pandas DataFrame column naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964380/pandas-dataframe-column-naming-conventions). I couldn't find anything on PEP8 from quick glances. The solution provided here offers some general advice but no standard leaving it to the developer's prerogative.

```py
import pandas as pd

col_names =  ['MyColumn1', 'Mycolumn2']
my_df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
```

It looks like snake case looks appropriate from my personal perspective, but I want to know what is the standard and if PEP8 has any guidance.

Comment: I would just follow the same [naming conventions for variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) as laid out in PEP8 i don't know of any specific rules just for Pandas but if someone does please correct me. Also of course avoid any reserved keywords in python as well

Comment: As long as it does not contains space and special characters, it's fine. And you can always follow the same principal as naming variables in PEP8, just use snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

It is really up to you how you name the columns as it is application- or problem specific. At least PEP8 does not care about this and a linter such as [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) will not complain.